# Dimension of a splitting field over a field $K$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field

I have to show that **a splitting field over** *$K$* **for a polynomial of  deg $n$  is generated over *$K$* by any $n-1$ roots of the polynomial**.

I know that if $c$ is algebraic over *$K$* of degree $n$ then *$K(c)$* is generated by ${1,c,c^2, \dots , c^m}$ , where $m=n-1$ over *$K$*.I thought it will be helpful in the problem, but that's not the case.

I think I have to show that if $\alpha_1,\alpha_2, \dots , \alpha_n $ are $n$ roots of a polynomial of degree $n$ over *$K$* in the splitting field $\mathcal S$ , then $\mathcal S =$ span{any of the $(n-1)$ roots of the polynomial }

Obviously $\mathcal S =$ *$K(\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \dots , \alpha_n)$*

Any help.Thank You.

Comment: The statement you're trying to prove doesn't make sense as written. First, a degree $n$ polynomial has $n$ roots, not $n-1$. Furthermore, it's not necessarily true that the splitting field of a polynomial is generated by only one of its roots. For example, the splitting field of $x^3 - 2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is larger than what you get by adjoining one root to $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Something is amiss with your question.  As stated it's not true.  Perhaps you mean that the splitting field of a polynomial of degree $n$ is generated by $n-1$ of its roots?

Comment: Yes..they are roots..

Comment: Any polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots,where did I say that the splitting field will be obtained by adjoining only one root ? @user263190

Comment: The phrase "...is generated over $K$ by any of its $n-1$ roots" is equivalent in meaning to  "The polynomial has $n-1$ roots and the splitting field is generated by adjoining any one of them." You must have meant to say something else, like "is generated by any set of $n-1$ of its roots." (admittedly it took me a couple minutes to put together that phrase and I'm still not entirely happy with it).

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look.

Comment: You must mean, generated by any $n-1$ of its roots. And that's true because if $n-1$ of the roots are there, then the missing root is guaranteed to be there as well, since the sum of all $n$ roots is in $K$ (it's a coefficient of the polynomial).

Comment: Yes.. How I will I solve it ?

Comment: I think I just told you how to solve it. The sum of the $n$ roots is in $K$ – do you understand that, and see why it's true? So any extension of $K$ that contains $n-1$ of the roots, since it also contains the sum of all $n$ of the roots, must contain every one of the $n$ roots (since fields are closed under addition & subtraction). Do you understand that, and see why it's true? But if the extension contains all the roots, then it's a splitting field – do you understand that?

Comment: I got you sir !

Answer (score 1):

Let $c_1,\dots,c_{n-1}$ be any $n-1$ roots of the polynomial $f$ of which we want to compute the splitting field $\mathcal{S}$. Obviously we have $K(c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})\subset \mathcal{S}$. The question is if the last root, $c_n$ is an element of $K(c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})$. But if you look at the factorization of the polynomial $f$ in $K(c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})[X]$, you can divide out any of the roots $c_1,\dots ,c_{n-1}$ so the remaining term is also a linear factor, the factor $(X-c_n)$. So $f=\prod_{i=1}^n(X-c_i)$ in $K(c_1,\dots,c_{n-1})$, hence it is the splitting field $\mathcal{S}$.